# Max iterations for NestWhileList

Tags: functional-style, procedural-programming

I'm writing Turing machines with a halting state. Many of these tms will never reach the halt state and I want a way to tweak `NestWhileList` so it runs a max of $n$ steps at a time.

How can I tweak this code so that it only runs $n$ steps at a time **and stop running when the test is no longer true**?

`NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, # > 1 &, 1, \[Infinity], -1]`

It prints `{20, 10, 5, 2, 1}`, how can I make it make it print only `{20, 10}`? Is there a `$MaxIterations` option?

`NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, # > 1 &, All, n]` doesn't do what I want because it can go beyond what I ask (I don't want extra output when the TM reaches the halt state and I don't want numbers that are `<= 1` in this example.)

edit: Here's the TM code

```
TMStep[rule_List, {s_, a_List, n_}] /; 1 <= n <= Length[a] := 
 Apply[{#1, ReplacePart[a, #2, n], n + #3} &, 
  Replace[{s, a[[n]]}, rule]]

TMEvolveList4[rule_, init_List, haltState_Integer] := 
 NestWhileList[TMStep[rule, #] &, init,  
  First[#] != haltState && #[[-1]] != 0 &, 1, \[Infinity], -1]
```

and here's a sample output

```
haltingRule = {{1, 1} -> {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0} -> {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1} -> {2, 0, -1}, {2, 0} -> {1, 0, 1}}; ArrayPlot[
 TMEvolveList4[haltingRule, {1, Table[0, {30}], 15}, 0][[All, 2]]]
```

Comment: Well, then why did you set the fifth argument to `∞`?

Comment: @J.M. Because `NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, # > 1 &, All, n]` doesn't do what I want. Note that if I specify n = 2 I get the result of 2 iterations, but if I do n = 5 I get trash.

Comment: @andandandand I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the arguments you are supplying.

1st) The function to apply repeatedly.
2nd) The first element in the list to start off the iterations.
3rd) The test to know when to stop iterating.
4th) How many of the previous arguments will be supplied to the test.
5th) The maximum number of times to apply the function in the 1st argument.

Comment: @C.Woods can you please explain a proper use of the arguments I'm supplying to provide the desired output?

Comment: Yes I just did, I hit enter trying to space out the list of arguments I was describing, but that ended up sending my comment prematurely. Basically, take your first line of code and change Infinity to the number of items you want returned.

Comment: @J.M.The fifth argument is infinite because one never knows when (and if) a TM halts. The code is just an abbreviated way to to explain the test. I'll post my TM code.

Comment: I think you'll have to better explain your question, then. If you know you want exactly n items out of the NestWhileList, then you should put an n in place of the infinity. If you mean something else by "it only runs n steps at a time," then you'll have to expand on that.

Comment: @C.Woods a fifth argument as n = maxIterations doesn't work for what I want because if maxIterations goes beyond the halt state it will produce trash.

Comment: Then you will really need to explain more what you want, because it is not clear from your question or comments. EDIT: I guess I see a little bit better what you are saying. But in that case, why is the halt state not part of the test in the first argument? You might need to provide more than a toy example for us to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43053/discussion-between-andandandand-and-c-woods).

Comment: In the simple case of your first example `NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, # > 1 &, 1, ∞, -3]` produces the output requested.  However this question seems to have arisen as the result of a misunderstanding and discussed in the chat linked above.  You amended your question with a new example but you did not explain what is wrong the behavior of the code; how does it fail you and when?

Answer (score 1):

`Most[NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, # > 1 &, 1, n = 100]]`

gives the desired output. Thanks at C. Woods for clarifying the role of `NestWhileList`'s penultimate parameter, `All` is unneeded as we only want to take into account the last evaluation.

This + `Most` avoids printing garbage after the halt condition is reached.

Comment: You can use the sixth parameter to avoid `Most[]`.

Comment: @J.M. NestWhileList[Floor[#/2] &, 20, # > 1 &, 1, n, -1], true, thanks.